# ERROR: How to fix - " Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResource'

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

The image contains the error message that is displayed when I try to run the default code "hello world" on a newly installed android studio project please check out this link to view screenshots, i would really appreciate your help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UheRn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the -offline in Command-line options here:

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler 
or
Preferences > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler